# Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\farm.com\mailconfig.php on line 2

Tags: php, string, undefined, string-concatenation

I'm try to send email with html5 template, my code is also working but it shows warning message

**Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\farming.com\mailconfig.php on line 2**

```
<?php
    $message.='<!DOCTYPE>';
    $message.='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
    $message.='<head>';
    $message.='<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />';
    $message.='<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
    $message.='<style>
          * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 1.6;
    }';
$message.='</head><body><table class="body-wrap"><tr><td></td><td class="container" width="600"><div class="content"><table class="main" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="alert alert-warning">Farmingarms</td></tr><tr><td class="content-wrap"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="content-block">Hi '.$name.',<br>Your login password has been changed.</td></tr><tr><td class="content-block"> If you believe this is an error, please click on the button below to visit our support portal, through which you can contact our support team</tr></td><br><tr><td class="content-block"><a style="color:white;" href='.$actual_link.' class="btn-primary">Contact Us</a></td></tr><br><tr><td class="content-block">Thanks for choosing Farming.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="footer"><table width="100%"><tr><td class="aligncenter content-block"><a href="www.farmingarms.com">Unsubscribe</a> from these alerts.</td></tr></table></div></div></td><td></td></tr></table></body></html>';
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            $error = "mail sended successfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can post comment instead of answer for one liner

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @gp_sflover To my extreme surprise, no where on that massive suggested dupe page is there an example of `.=` being used -- so it is poorly suited for this closure.

Comment: @mickmackusa Interesting. I haven't the time now, but don't you think it would be the case to add an example to the dupe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined variable when declaring with concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359427/undefined-variable-when-declaring-with-concatenation)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10605842/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35345747/2943403

Answer (score 2):

```
$message.='<!DOCTYPE>';
```

In the line above there is an undefined variable warning error in your code. warning error can be ignored they are not critical errors that is why your code is working. [click here to read more about PHP errors](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-types-of-errors-in-PHP). 
*"In PHP '.' is the sign of ConCatination"*

**Explaination** 
`$message.='<!DOCTYPE>';` means your are concatinating `'<!DOCTYPE>'` in the variable $message, your first Need to define the variable $message.

You can do it either by just writing `$message="";` in the start of your code or you can also start like `$message='<!DOCTYPE>';` like the above answers.